# Using <C-,> causes "<80>ü^D," to flash in the showcmd area?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, terminal

I've mapped `<C-,>` as well as some other special keys (`<C-Enter>`, `<C-S-Space>`, ...) in my vimrc like,

```
:set  <F13>=^[[44;5u
:map  <F13> <C-,>
:map! <F13> <C-,>
```

and configured iTerm to send `^[[44;5u` when `<C-,>` is typed.

(Note that `^[` is the ascii Escape character.)

It works great, but Vim flashes `<80>ü^D,` in the showcmd area whenever I use `<C-,>`. Here's a screenshot (see the bottom-right corner):

[image]

It doesn't inhibit the mapping or seem to cause any problems, I'm just curious what it indicates. None of my other special mappings (`<C-Enter>` and the like) do this.

Do you know?

Comment: In gvim, whenever you enter a command, it will be shown at the bottom right corner until the operation is completed. Say if you type 1800dd, until you type the last d, 1800d is shown. It might be like that feature.

Comment: It looks like `<80>ü^D,` is simply the way `^[[44;5u` is internally represented in Vim, but I can't really track down why from the source code.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker that is correct.

Comment: In `insert` mode, try this: Hit `<C-V>` and then `<C-,>` this will insert the sequence of keys Vim tracked from Shell. Note `<C-K>` is same as `<C-V>`.

Answer (score 1):

`<80>ü^D,` is how Vim displays its four-byte internal representation of `<C-,>`:

#### First byte: `<80>`

This is how Vim displays the byte 0x80. This value is [`K_SPECIAL`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/605d02a9b73cb49ac5022a127db3eac7e16a5d83/src/keymap.h#L22). It is the first byte of a "special" keycode, and it is always followed by two bytes.

### Second byte: `ü`

This is how Vim displays the byte 0xFC (the Unicode character [`U+00FC`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=00FC) is LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS).

0xFC (or 252 in decimal) is [`KS_MODIFIER`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/605d02a9b73cb49ac5022a127db3eac7e16a5d83/src/keymap.h#L64), and it means that the third byte will be a bitmask specifying which modifier was pressed.

### Third byte: `^D`

This is how Vim displays `CTRL-D`, the byte 0x04. In this context, 0x04 is
[`MOD_MASK_CTRL`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/605d02a9b73cb49ac5022a127db3eac7e16a5d83/src/keymap.h#L492).

#### Bytes 1–3: `<80>ü^D`

So, putting these together, we see that `<80>ü^D` means `<C-`

### Fourth byte: `,`

This one is simpler to figure out. It means `,`.

### In combination

So the four bytes `<80>ü^D,` means `<C-,>`, which is what you entered (via the mapping), and Vim
helpfully displays this in the `'showcmd'` area, as you requested!